# L2S DBML Table Stuck as "Internal" Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq to SQL data context with several tables. One particular table is marked in the DBML designer as having Public access, however when I save and compile the assembly it always changes the access modifier in the .designer file to internal. Thus the build always fails (as I have classes in other assemblies that reference this table) and I have to go into the .designer file and change the internal modifier back to public. Any change to the DBML file at all causes this to happen, even if I specifically set the property in the designer (toggle it back and forth, whatever). Is this a bug in VS (problem experienced in VS2010 and VS2013) and is there a fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have finally found a solution:

1. Open the .dbml file outside Visual Studio (e.g. Notepad)
2. Locate the problematic table definition.
3. Change `AccessModifier="Internal"` to `AccessModifier="Public"`
4. Save and close the .dbml file
5. Update the table definitions in the .designer.cs file with the `public` modifier if you have not already done so.

In theory the dbml designer should be doing this for me when I change that property on the table but unfortunately it doesn't for these particular tables. Following these steps fixed the problem.